# Finding a Programable Stand-Alone QR Scanner

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner

Here's what I need to do:

1. Select a single parameter from a screen (preferable) OR enter a code for that single parameter.
2. Scan a QR code
3. Update my MySQL database with the data.
4. Return 'success' or 'failure' in some form (Preferably with bit of explanation)

--

What I can't find is a scanner that communicates directly with my remote server.

I'm considering a smartphone app, but nobody's thrilled to use their personal phone for work.

I've looked at many scanners, but they all connect to a smartphone or computer. I need a programmable standalone device to talk directly with my server.

I'm considering building the scanner out of an arduino or Rhaspberry Pi. It sounds simple enough (not that I have experience in such), but I have a hard time believing this product doesn't already exist.

I'm open to any advice/direction.

Comment: Why not buy a phone to use as a dedicated scanner?

Comment: I forgot to mention that we need every client to purchase a scanner and they should be water proof. A cheap Android phone in an otterbox could be a good solution.

Comment: Buy an old Samsung Galaxy 1 at less than 50$, they will be perfect for this, coupled with ZXing library to decode the QRcode, then a call to your webserver.

Comment: Thanks guys. If nobody chimes in with a more professional device to meet my needs, it looks like I'll go with the Galaxy. Or really, any phone that I can buy a batch of about 50 of.